# php_uploadprogress.dll on with XAMPP 1.7.3. for windows 7 professional

Tags: php, xampp, pecl

I'm trying to setup the pecl uploadprogress extension on my localhost development computer. It's a windows 7 home professional machine with XAMPP 1.7.3.

After making and installing the extension it refused to start with:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: uploadprogress: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply need to find the proper version of the dll or replace php with the matching version. you could also compile the library yourself...

you can find everything here: http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress